# F# Namespaces/Modules and Interop with C#

Tags: c#, f#, interop

I've been experimenting with F# and would like to try using it in a C# project for certain pieces of code that would benefit from the language.

I've been trying to figure out how Modules and Namespaces work when used within a C# project. For example, the following code:

```
namespace File1
#light

type File1(path : string) =
    static member Trim(p : string) = p.Trim()
    member self.Path = path
```

Then I try to use this in C# by saying:

```
using File1;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Doesn't work
        Console.WriteLine(File1.Trim(" hello "));
        // Does work
        Console.WriteLine(File1.File1.Trim(" hello "));
    }
}
```

I understand why the second one works, but why doesn't the first one work? I've pulled in the namespace with the using declaration and File1 should be a class. Trim is a static member of that class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not caused by the way namespaces and classes behave in F#, you got that right.

The problem is that you have a namespace called `File1` and a class called `File1`. When you write `File1` in your C# program, even if you have the correct `using`, it means “namespace `File1`”, not “class `File1.File1`”. If, for example, you changed the name of your namespace to `FileNamespace` and the name of the `type` to `FileType`, everything would work as expected. (I'm not saying you should use naming like this in your actual project.)

Comment: That makes sense. Changing one of the names to just File worked.